# I want to extract a specific data from a json string

Tags: php, json

This is my code , how can I achieve it plz help

```
<?php

$json = '
{
    "type": "donut",
    "name": "Cake",
    "toppings": [{"data":
        { "id": "5002", "type": "Glazed" },
        { "id": "5006", "type": "Chocolate with Sprinkles" },
        { "id": "5004", "type": "Maple" }
    }]
}';

$yummy = json_decode($json);

echo $yummy->toppings[0]->data[2]->id;
```

Comment: That's not valid JSON. You're missing the `[]` around the `data:` array.

Comment: Fix the JSON and your code will work.

Comment: Or get rid of the `{"data:" ... }` object. Just make `toppings` a single level of array.

Answer (score 0):

Fix the JSON, you're missing brackets. Once you fix this your code will work (it returns 5004 in your example)

```
{
    "type": "donut",
    "name": "Cake",
    "toppings": [{"data":
            [{ "id": "5002", "type": "Glazed" },
            { "id": "5006", "type": "Chocolate with Sprinkles" },
            { "id": "5004", "type": "Maple" }]
        }]
}
```

There are online tools that help you find these little issues.

https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/